# In Interpreting the results of chi-squared. Does this relationship appear to be linear or non-linear?

Tags: statistics

Problem: 
People with more education are often stereotyped as being more liberal than people with less education and therefore might be more likely to attribute inequality to discrimination. Is there a relationship between educational degrees attained (degree) and attitudes about discrimination (racdif1)? The table below shows the correctly percentaged table with χ2 and the associated p-value for 2010:

Chart given: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBchB.jpg

Was able to get a lot of information such as:

$$df = 2 $$

$$\alpha = 0.05$$

$$\chi^2_{critical} = 5.991 $$

$$\chi^2_{achieved} = 8.1784 $$

Because the achieved is greater than the critical, we can reject the null hypothesis.

What I am wondering is in interpreting the chi-square (including a substantive interpretation of the results). Does this relationship appear to be linear or nonlinear?

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Chi-Square Test for Independence has nothing to do with a relationship being linear or non-linear. It is simply a test to determine if one categorical variable is associated with another categorical variable. The hypotheses are as follows:

$$H_0: \text{Highest degree and attributing inequality to discrimination are independent}$$

$$H_a: \text{Highest degree and attributing inequality to discrimination are associated}$$

In your case, as you correctly determined, you would reject the null hypothesis at $\alpha=0.05$ and conclude that we have significant evidence of an association.

Comment: Understood. There must be something in there which is linear/non-linear. A problem is worded exactly like: Interpret chi-square (include a substantive interpretation of the results).  Does this relationship appear to be linear or nonlinear?

Comment: That is very strange. Two categorical variables cannot have a linear relationship, as they are not continuous.

Comment: Than that is the answer as you stated. It is non-linear.

Comment: Well, non-linear would usually mean quadratic or other non-linear relationships between two continuous random variables.